# How do I set access permissions per field?

Tags: 8, entities

**What I need to do**

I have some user account fields that should be administrator-only (read/write/edit).  For example, the IP address used to register.

So, I want to restrict access to administrators.

**Current state of field permissions in Drupal 8 (as of Feb 19, 2016)**

- In Drupal 7, I used the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.  However, [a Drupal 8 version is not currently being worked on by the maintainers.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2196303)
- There is a [discussion on putting field permissions in Core](https://www.drupal.org/node/366416), but this has been going on for seven years and is marked as "postponed."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an old thread, but as I stumbled upon same problem, not wanting to use a heavy module for few fields, I ran into this article (after this one, so I thought I could share) : 
https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/form-and-view-modes-vs-field-access-drupal-8

From other exemples around, this one takes care of cache context .

Just be careful to comments below article and some other little mistakes in code example. Correct and working code looks like this :

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_entity_field_access($operation, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, AccountInterface $account, FieldItemListInterface $items = NULL) {
  $result = AccessResult::neutral();
  if ($field_definition->getName() == 'field_we_care_about') {
    if ($operation == 'edit' && !in_array('administrator', $account->getRoles())) {
      $result = AccessResult::forbidden();
    }
  }
  return $result->addCacheContexts(['user.roles:administrator']);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to write the code yourself, the [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module includes a `field_permissions` example module.

After missing the Drupal 8 cycle, Field Permissions finally got a release for Drupal 9, so you can install the module now.

Comment: My use case was to modify visibility of one of two fields in a Paragraph. But in the edit form I needed to show it as an item and not an editable field. Which is beyond the scope of the Field permissions module. So thanks for pointing out the examples.

Comment: @PatrickKenny, Field Permissions has a full release now.

Comment: @ChrisHappy Thanks for letting me know. Updated the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

[Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) has a full release for D8 now. It allows you to set permissions per field.

Comment: [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module has a full 1.0 release now.